# How to Determine encoding pattern of flash player and decode it

Tags: flash, adobe, encode

I'm using a flash player application and it encoded text and create an output text file in such a way. If I write below input string and save the file at any path. The output file shows the text like below output text:

**Input string :** **This tool is cool !**

**Output String:** **et7W2NyL1JCTrt/MrsmQrtmQ1JP6rj**

I checked many decoder online but none of those were able to determine the encoding pattern. could you please help me in determining the encoding pattern.

Comment: Do you have a link to this application so we see exactly what it's doing? What is output string for **a**? Then **b**? Then **c**? Now what about for **abc**?. If your input string was base64'ed then it would have 28 chars but your shown output string has 30 chars. Since only you have experience with the app, is there anything else we should know? How can we recreate your issue?

Comment: I created the file for the requested string
A = jj , B = j6, AB = jfr, a = bj, b= b6, ab = bfr..
If you want more encoded strings, i will provide you.

Comment: I have that app with me and i can translate any text in the encoding pattern.. I checked many decoder online but none of them work ..